# Change login to logout when the credentials is correct in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Even if it wrong credentials it change the login to logout but it when it is null it still login. because of the if functions customer.User != null, how can I do if it is wrong credentials

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      @{
                    AccountContactVM customer = (AccountContactVM)ViewBag.AccountData;
                }

                @if (customer.User != null)
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-fw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>@customer.User.FirstName @customer.User.LastName<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li class="disabled">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle" style="font-size:40px;padding:5px 20px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <p style="padding-top:5px;">
                                            @customer.User.FirstName @customer.User.LastName <br />
                                            @customer.Company.AccountName
                                        </p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index">Customer Portal</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOut">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignUp">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a></li>
                }
                <li ng-cloak><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Cart")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></i>Cart(<strong>{{CartCount}}</strong>)</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is my controller code for the view
Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult SignIn(UserLogin user)
    {
        //Account Varialble
        Models.CustomerModel.Account account = new Models.CustomerModel.Account();

        //Contact Variable
        Models.CustomerModel.Contact contact = new Models.CustomerModel.Contact();

        AccountContactVM customer = new AccountContactVM();


        var a = user.Password.GetHashCode();
        ViewBag.CartItemCount = cartItemCount;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            LoginAction login = new LoginAction();
            contact = login.ContactProfile(user);
            if (contact.ContactId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                if(contact.Authenticated == false)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Your account is not confirmed.";

                    customer.Company = account;
                    customer.User = contact;
                    ViewBag.AccountData = customer;
                    return View(user);
                }else
                {
                    account = login.AccountProfile(contact.AccountId);
                    if (account.AccountId != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        customer.Company = account;
                        customer.User = contact;
                        helper.SetObject("accountcustomer", customer);
                        ViewBag.AccountData = customer;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
                    }

                    ViewBag.AccountData = customer;
                    ViewBag.Message = "Unable to find company profile";
                    return View(user);
                }

            }

            customer.Company = account;
            customer.User = contact;

            ViewBag.AccountData = customer;
            ViewBag.Message = "Invalid credentials";
            return View(user);

        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add code from your controller where you check user credentials?

Comment: Yes, I already edited it

Comment: There are several options how you could implement this. One more thing to clarify - what do you mean by "logout"? Which part of your view is "logout"?

Comment: he means that for example..
Register|Login into Name|Logout

Comment: Yes it is @Woshooo

Comment: @PNam I've posted my answer based on what I was able observe from your code. Please give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing your requirements.

- Even if user login credentials are incorrect, you still want to display "Login" part of the view.

Personally, I am not quite sure about the business reason here...

Anyway, from your controller's code I am assuming that `contact` object returned by `login.ContactProfile(user)` is never null and when `contact.ContactId` is an empty GUID, then user has entered wrong credentials, and this results in "Invalid credentials" message.

As a simple solution following existing coding style would be to add additional condition to your `if` in the view. See below.

```
@if (customer.User != null || (customer.User != null && customer.User.ContactId == Guid.Empty)
```

I don't see code from all your classes, therefore this solution is based on the assumption above.

And ideally I would refactor code to have different partial views and dedicated view model, however this would be much bigger effort.